# Predict most probable document in a given set of documents by a given question

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I would like to know / discuss which implementation would be the best solution to predict to a given question the document from a given set of documents which is has the highest probability of including the answer.

Given the following documents:

```
- The email address the school is school@school.com.
- Marc Zuckerburg is the class teacher
- The Website can be accessed under http://google.com
- You have to do your work within your working hours
- The email address of the teacher is teacher@school.com
- Email addresses are an usual way to communicate nowadays
- The message from the teacher arrived at the parent's house
- To become a teacher you've to go to school before
- If I would become a teacher I would like to teach my students well
- The school is located near the moon
```

Given the following question:

```
- How can I reach out the class teacher?
```

The result should map to the following document out of the set of given doucments:

```
- The email address of the teacher is teacher@school.com
```

What I have tried so far with modest results:

1. Using [Spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy) document similarity api (i.e. loading each of the given document in a set of a document into spacy and using .similarity to compare each of the given documents to the given question)
2. Using keyword similarity using [KeyBERT](https://github.com/MaartenGr/KeyBERT) (i.e. loading keywords for each of the given documents and compare the to the keywords of the question)
3. Using [BERTScore](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score)
4. Question similarity using [Question Generation](https://github.com/patil-suraj/question_generation) (i.e. loading related questions to each of the given document and compare them to the given question)

All these approchases don't perform well, around 50-60% accuracy.

This question aims not to get a fully implemented code, all I want is to talk about architecture. Any ideas about how to realize this kind of problem to achive better results as I've seen so far?

Comment: This is an area of active research, and you’re benchmarking some state-of-the-art approaches.